# Draw an elliptical or circular arc using polyline path in SVG

Tags: interpolation, curves

I am exporting a 2D profile containing elleptical/circular arcs from CATIA V5 into a SVG file. Paths for for arcs are represented as a polylines in SVG. This is causing problems while calculating properties of arcs in SVG. Please suggest if there is a way to fit an elliptical/circular arc for a given ployline. Thanks in advance.

Comment: If I understand correctly, you have a bunch of points connected by edges that make up your polyline, and you are asking for a way to interpolate the points with a circular/elliptical arc?

Comment: hi josh, yes. I just have points. Eventually, I need to calculate radius for arcs